Updating components with CSV import without moving them
I import CSV files containing data for existing components in EA. The import files contain the columns GUID, CSV_KEY and CSV_PARENT_KEY, which uniquely identify the components. The data comes from multiple packages.
It seems that when I import the data, the components are all moved to the single package which I select (you have to select a single package) when starting the import (Publish->CSV->CSV Import/Export). This happens despite "Preserve Hierarchy" being enabled in the import specification.


I don't want the components to move. Is there a way to accomplish this?
